# Error: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to setting up Cake Console and Bake..So This Is My Path-

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\lib\Cake\Console
```

If we talk about bin folder,there is no bin folder in my cakephp version..Please suggest me..

Comment: Are you using composer? If you are will you consider `composer update`?

Comment: Also please inform which OS you are using and which server (i.e. Wamp or Xampp) you are running.

Answer (score 3):

Cake is a PHP framework, so make sure that you can run `php -v` from the command prompt and get a response. If not, find out where the php executable is located. I'm not a Windows guy, so I'm not sure how to ensure running command `x` points to `\path\to\command\x`, but from a quick good, it looks like you need to add the following to your windows path environment variable: `;C:\xampp\php;`

Further googling found these steps for ya

- Right click on "My Computer" and select "properties"
- Select the "Advanced Tab"
- Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom
- Under the "System Variables" list find the "Path" variable and click "edit"
- Now add the full path of your Php directory in your server e.g. `;C:\xampp\php` separated by a comma.

Credit goes to http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/baking_with_cakephp